# How to determine the difference in dates in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, compare

I have some problem with comparing dates. I need to compare more than `DateTime.now` or `record.updated_at` for 7 days.
I try do something like that: `DateTime.now` - `record.updated_at` but have result as that `143587.77856945992` or `(14358777856939/8640000000000)`.
I dont understand what is that. Maybee need convert to `Time` format or something else? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
((DateTime.now - record.updated_at) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i
```

to get the number of seconds

```
(DateTime.now - record.updated_at).to_i
```

to get the number of days (obviously...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want in words then you can use distance_of_time_in_words

Comment: This is not exactly what i need, but thank you. I know where it might need for me